what is the proper order for three verbs at the end of a sentence when there is no ersatz infinitive?
I am working on a translation of a video game and I have a few cases where I want to use three verbs at the end of a sentence. For example,

The barrel is used for storing emergency rations, in case the thieves' lodge needs to lie low for a while.


Das Faß benutzt man, um Notverpflegung zu lagern, falls die Diebenloge eine Weile sich versteckt halten muss.

In school I remember learning that where there are three verbs at the end of a sentence or clause, the conjugated one goes before the other two. These posts here seem to cover this, but are referring to
clauses with an "ersatz infinitive," which I do not have here. So does the conjugated verb go at the end in my case, i.e. "sich versteckt halten muss" or is it still "muss sich versteckt halten?"

Is the thieves' lodge the one who uses the barrel? Then "benutzt man" sounds odd, as it implies that someone else uses the barrel.

@mkrieger1: I think it depends on whether the speaker's point of view is within the thieves' lodge or from outside of it. If it is from within - and this can include a third person description of a group as seen from the perspective of the group - it is quite usual to mix "man" and a descriptor for the group.

You have to move the sich as pronoun accusative objects go before adverbials as eine Weile.

Das Faß benutzt man, um Notverpflegung zu lagern, falls die Diebenloge sich eine Weile versteckt halten muss.

Actually, in this case you could even argue that eine Weile is part of the verb phrase because it's the same for a noun accusative object in this context:

Das Faß benutzt man, um Notverpflegung zu lagern, falls die Diebenloge ihre Mitglieder eine Weile versteckt halten muss.


If you know English, the rule for German verb order is simple: reverse to English. With that additional rule that the conjugated verb without its prefixes is moved to second position in main clauses.
